# Convert rgb to png with imagemagik

Tags: imagemagick

I am trying to convert some image (raw) that has no header, just the pixel values to a png, so I can view it. I found some information [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=15554) (using imageMagik) and it works if the image is one channel. I used the command

```
convert -depth 8 -size 5312x2988+0 gray:image.raw pic.png
```

I searched more and I found that using the rpg is a way to treat more channels image, so I changed the syntax to

```
convert -depth 8 -size 5312x2988+0 rgb:image.raw pic.png
```

... but the output seems to be more like a 9x9 matrix containing the small images, like

```
R R R
G G G
B B B
```

The size is not wrong, but it may be the way the pixels are stored (interlaced/not-interlaced).

Can anyone help me to convert the 3-channel image, the correct way?

Comment: You could try specifying `-interlace plane` before the input file. Or maybe `-interlace line`. Or share the file and I will have a try.

Comment: What's generating the raw data? If the results are RRRGGGBBB, that makes me think it's not a 16bit stream.

Comment: @emcconville sorry, it's a mistake there, I tried more things and it seems I copied the wrong line, the depth is 8 (I edited)

Comment: @MarkSetchell that's it the planes were interlaced, you may put it into an answer, so I can accept it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try specifying `-interlace plane` before the input file. Or maybe `-interlace line`, like this:

```
convert -interlace plane -depth 8 -size 5312x2988+0 rgb:image.raw pic.png
```

Like many **ImageMagick** parameters, you can enumerate the options at the command line with `identify -list OPTION`, so, in this case:

```
identify -list interlace
```

**Output**

```
Line
None
Plane
Partition
GIF
JPEG
PNG
```